# Finding Big-O, Omega and theta

Tags: algorithm, big-o, discrete-mathematics

I've looked through the links, and I'm too braindead to understand the mechanical process of figuring them out. I understand the ideas of O, theta and omega, and I understand the "Rules". So let me work on this example with you guys to clear this up in my head :)

f(n) = 100n+logn

g(n) = n+(logn)2

I need to find: whether f = O(g), or f = Ω(g), or both (in which case f = Θ(g))

so I know that 100n and n are the same, and they are both slower than log(n). I just need to figure out if (log(n))^2 is slower or faster. but I can't really remember anything about logs. if the log(n) is bigger, does it mean the number gets bigger or smaller?

let me please add my real struggle is in figuring out BOTH omega and theta. By definition f(n) <= g(n) if there is a constant c that will make g(n) bigger, and same for the reverse for omega. but how do I really test this?

Comment: The Windows calculator has a log function.  Log some n's and see what results you get.  As for what the log function is:  y = log(x).  10^y = x.  You can use other bases, replace the 10 with whatever base you are using.  I've never seen other values besides 2 and e.  (The latter are called natural logarithms.)

Answer (score 1):

You can usually figure it out from these rules:

1. Broadly `k < log(n)^k < n^k < k^n`.  You can replace `k` at each step with any positive number you want and it remains true for large enough `n`.
2. If `x` is big, then `1/x` is very close to 0.
3. For positive `x` and `y`, `x < y` if and only if `log(x) < log(y)`.  (Sometimes taking logs can help with complicated and messy products.
4. `log(k^n) = log(k) n`.
5. For O, theta, and omega, you can ignore everything except the biggest term that doesn't cancel out.

Rules 1 and 5 suffice for your specific questions.  But learn all of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remember rules, but rather learn general principles.

Here, all you need to know is that log(n) is increasing and grows without limit, and the definition of big-O, namely f = O(g) if there's a c such that for all sufficiently large n, f(n) <= c * g(n). You might learn the fact about log by remembering that log(n) grows like the number of digits of n.

Can log^2(n) be O(log(n))? That would mean (using the definition of big-O) that log^2(n) <= c.log(n) for all sufficiently large n, so log^2(n)/log(n) <= c for sufficiently large n (*). But log^2(n)/log(n) = log(n), which grows without limit, so can't be bounded by c. So log^2(n) = O(log(n)).

Can log(n) be O(log^2(n))? Well, at some point log(n) > 1 (since it's increasing without limit), and from that point on, log(n) < log^2(n). That proves that log(n) = O(log^2(n)), with the constant c equal to 1.

(*) If you're being extra careful, you need to exclude the possibility that log(n) is infinitely many times zero.